# Logout happens immediately upon logging in to a user account

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I create a user account for my daughter and when I try to log on, it immediately logs right back off.  It says welcome loging on and then the screen flashes and goes into logging off. I can log on with my Administrator account no problem. Guest account logs off immediately as well.

What is causing this to happen? 
How can I fix the accounts to work as they should?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a startup script, use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check for possible culprits.